# Javscript - Three.js Disable panning on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js

So I'm making a 3d project with three.js. Everything works as expected on my laptop. I'm using `OrbitControls` to allow camera movement, but i have disabled right click panning, because I want the camera just to rotate. When switching to a mobile device (iphone), using two fingers I'm able to move the camera (not rotate). Is there a way to disable this behaviour on mobile devices?
My OrbitControls:

```
this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement)
this.controls.enableDamping = true
this.controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.45
this.controls.mouseButtons = {
  LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
  MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
  RIGHT: ''
}
```

Update function:

```
_RAF() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.water.material.uniforms[ 'time' ].value += 1.0 / 60.0
      this.controls.maxDistance = 10000.0
      this.controls.minDistance = 10.0
      this.controls.update()
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
      this._RAF()
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're not disabling panning, but just changing the mouse action used by controls.

In order to disable/enable panning, you should use [enablePan](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enablePan).

Now, you only want to disable panning in mobile, so we could pick a *break-point* for conditionally enable/disable panning:

```js
this.controls.updatePanning = () => {
  const minWidth = 780 // Your min breakpoint for enabling pan.
  if (window.innerWidth >= minWidth ) {
    this.controls.enablePan = true
  } else {
    this.controls.enablePan = false
  }
}
```

Then, in your update loop, just invoke the above function:

```js
_RAF() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.water.material.uniforms[ 'time' ].value += 1.0 / 60.0
      this.controls.maxDistance = 10000.0
      this.controls.minDistance = 10.0
      this.controls.updatePanning()
      this.controls.update()
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
      this._RAF()
    })
  }
```

You could approach this in several ways. For example: You could only execute this function once and not every frame.

Comment: Just with the line `this.controls.enablePan = false` does the trick.  Thanks!